# are In-App Payments for delivery app subject to 70/30 split as well?

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase

I am building an application for a restaurant to offer quick ordering and delivery for their customers. Do you know if these transactions are subject to the standard 70/30 split on both iOS and Android? Is there a way around this? This would render this application un-feasable if so.

Comment: On iOS you cannot use in-app purchases to pay for "real world" services such as food and delivery. ApplePay is the appropriate solution for that. In app purchases do have the 70/30 split (although that is changing for subscription renewals) while ApplePay merchant fees will depend on what you negotiate with your credit card acquirer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. According to the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#payments):

> 3.1.5 Physical Goods and Services Outside of the App: If your app enables people to purchase goods or services that will be consumed outside of the app, you must use purchase methods other than IAP to collect those payments, such as Apple Pay or traditional credit card entry. Apps may facilitate transmission of approved virtual currencies (e.g. Bitcoin, DogeCoin) provided that they do so in compliance with all state and federal laws for the territories in which the app functions.

You cannot have an app sell real world items through IAP. You'd have to use "Apple Pay or traditional credit card entry".

Answer (score 0):

For iOS Please Read this [App Review Guideline](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#payments)

as per Apples guideline you can't use InApp you can use any payment gateway like apple pay, paypal, skrill.

For Android

You can use any Payment gateways there is no restriction like apple :)